# (Pandas)I fail to assign value when I use loc and column name together

Tags: python, pandas

The sample of my data is as follows.

```
  date         traffic_amount      factor
-----------------------------------------------
2012-01-01       613.586982        1.000000
2012-02-01       598.591841        1.107143
2012-03-01       653.042743        1.000000
2012-04-01       666.692536        1.033333
```

I tried to change value which has index 2012-02-01 using loc and column name. But I failed to do that. The value remained the same.

```
data_per_member.loc['2012-02-01']['factor'] = 31/29
print(data_per_member.loc['2012-02-01']['factor'])

1.1071428571428572
```

31/29 is 1.0689655172413792.
So I noticed that my code 'data_per_member.loc['2012-02-01']['factor'] = 31/29' did not work. Why did not my code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not chain the `loc` with `[]`

```
data_per_member.loc['2012-02-01','factor'] = 31/29
```